# public key file encryption

Tags: c#, wcf, security

We are working on very sensitive data and need to encrypt it, we have decided to use public key encryption.

We basically need a master key that can decrypt everything, a public key which cycles every n days and encrypts everything and lastly a private key for each thing we encrypt.

I've read up on a lot of security and tried a few examples.

My manager says there is a default .net class `System.Security.Cryptography` that can do what we need but I'm not sure how to implement this kind of system.

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may start from here: "Generating Keys for Encryption and Decryption" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e9ft273(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Iv already implemented something similar but i dont know how to generate a master key.

Comment: I See. Can you ask your manager exactly what algorithm he is in mind?

Comment: A public key is public and will not change from time to time. To me, " a public key which cycles every n days" sounds like an OTP (One Time Password), not a public key.